# Tkinter changing image on a canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have written some code that displays a random question on a certain topic for maths students. The module definition presents the initial image on the topic chosen. Then the next question and mark scheme definitions are used under the respective buttons. The next question one works fine however because the mark scheme definition is linked the the module definition the question does not update. Resulting in only the mark scheme for the very first question showing. How can i get it to update with the next question button?

```
def module(mod):
    def mark_scheme():
        questions.delete('all')
        scheme=random_question.replace('.GIF', 'MS.GIF')
        answer=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=scheme)
        lab1.configure(image=answer)
        lab1.image=answer
        lab1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        return

    def next_question():

        questions.delete('all')
        random_question=random.choice(mod)
        question=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=random_question)
        lab1.configure(image=question)
        lab1.image=question
        lab1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        return

    questions=Canvas(root)
    questions.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    lab1=Label(questions)
    random_question=random.choice(mod)                            
    question=ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=random_question) 
    lab1.configure(image=question)
    lab1.image=question
    lab1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    button1=Button(root, text='Next Question', command=next_question).pack()
    button2=Button(root, text='Mark Scheme', command=mark_scheme).pack()
    return
```

Comment: Is there a reason why are using a closure to manage this rather than just a simple class? Also is the Canvas actually required?

Comment: could you give me an example? I'm not that experienced with python. No the canvas isn't required but it seemed like the easiest way to clear the screen and display a new picture because before they the new picture was appearing underneath the old one for some reason

Comment: Ah sorry didn't realise that. Tried to up vote it but said i couldn't so assumed i couldn't do anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of a `Canavas` widget here is unnecessary, as you can do all of this with just a simple `Label`. Similarly, your choice of using a closure to wrap up the code and stop the image references being garbage collected is a little unusual. You would likely be better moving to a simple class structure like the one below.

The example below shows how you can update a label image in Tkinter. Rather than random image selection, the code below just cycles through all the PNG files in the current directory.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk
import glob

IMAGES = glob.glob("*.png")
DEFAULT_IMAGE = IMAGES[0]

class QuestionWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)
        self.init_window()

    def update_image(self,move=0):
        """
        move = +1 jumps to the next image in the sequence
        move = -1 skips back to the previous image in the sequence
        move = +2 jumps... you get it.
        """
        self.img_idx += move
        fname = IMAGES[self.img_idx%len(IMAGES)]

        # here generate the image and make sure a reference is 
        # kept in the form of a class attribute.
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=fname)

        # set the label image.
        self.question_lbl.configure(image=self.img)

    def init_window(self):
        self.img_idx = 0

        # choose a default image for startup
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=DEFAULT_IMAGE)

        # This is the question label that will contain the image
        self.question_lbl = tk.Label(self,image=self.img)
        self.question_lbl.pack(anchor=tk.N, side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        # These are the next and prev buttons. Note that they are using lambdas to
        # generate partial functions that call update_image,
        self.next_btn = tk.Button(self,text="Next",command=lambda:self.update_image(+1))
        self.next_btn.pack(anchor=tk.S,side=tk.RIGHT)

        self.prev_btn = tk.Button(self,text="Previous",command=lambda:self.update_image(-1))
        self.prev_btn.pack(anchor=tk.S,side=tk.LEFT)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    qw = QuestionWindow(root)
    qw.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

As it stands the window will resize depending on the image that is being displayed, but this can be changed by fixing the window geometry.